# Use of a variable containing regular expression in SED

Tags: regex, unix, sed, pattern-matching

I am trying to delete lines mathcing a particular pattern.
My pattern is stored in a variable.

```
sed "/${iceclone_id_comb}/d" ${held_file_path}${held_file_name} > ${outputpath}Tempout.dat
```

but this is not working . The pattern is not getting matched and no lines are deleted.

The ${iceclone_id_comb} will have values as follows

300307569730.*006

300305422783.*006

however if I hardcode , then it will work

```
sed '/300307569730.*006/d' ${held_file_path}${held_file_name} > ${outputpath}Tempout.dat
```

os details

```
sshuser@hn0-iceprd:~/ProdHeld_April30$ uname -a
Linux hn0-iceprd 4.4.0-119-generic #143-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 2 16:08:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


sshuser@hn0-iceprd:~/ProdHeld_April30$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Comment: [I cannot repro](https://ideone.com/6qVD0m).

Comment: @TomG the `iceclone_id_comb` variable has only `300307569730.*006` or does it have `300305422783.*006` as well? do you get any error when you use the first sed command?

Comment: @Sundeep This command runs in a while loop. These two values get assigned to the variable in different iterations

Comment: ok.. try to create a sample that we can test.. for ex: create a small file with 5 words, create a loop assigning two different regex to a variable and see if matching lines are getting deleted.. if this works, then try changing the sample closer to your real use case

Comment: I such cases exact input and output string should be posted.

Comment: Put a `set -x` before the `sed` to check if the search string passed to sed is what you expect it to be.

Comment: and if MSwindows was involved (anywhere), then change MS-DOS line-endings to *nix line-endings with `dos2unix myFile.txt` . Good luck.